# Memory usage of a DNN model during inferencing

Tags: object-detection, gpu

I am running a DNN model (YOLOv7) on GPU to detect objects in a video stream. The memory usage on my task manager shows that I am using up to 2GB of my RAM!  The GPU Ram usage is almost 1 GB.
I am running everything on GPU, but have no idea why system memory usage is 2 GB.

Comment: You can use a memory profiler to understand how your process is consuming CPU memory.

Comment: You detect objects in a video stream. All this stuff stays in RAM and from RAM is copied in GPU memory only the part needed for prediction and the response is copied again in RAM. You have to watch out what the rest of the application is doing.

Comment: I am removing all detected objects, and the RAM usage is still 2 GB. I tested it on a single image too, and story is the same!